# Flutter Problems: Android Studio not found at /path/to/android/studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

[image]
Flutter doctor is showing me Errors in these categories. Although I have Flutter Dart plugins installed. I have also failed to understand the other problem. I am using Android Studio 3.2 and I need Help to fix this issue.

Comment: what is `/path/to/android/studio/`?? i dont really think it is correct... did you try to follow the advice from the first line out your `flutter doctor` command's output?

Comment: Consult the picture. I am not able to understand the problem. Any help would surely be Appreciated. Thank You for being Interested.

Comment: i already saw that picture... did you try to follow the advice from the first line of your `flutter doctor` command's output?

Comment: Thanks Bro. I found the solution. I was not running flutter doctor -v. In got the details and removed android dir. It is working good now without any problems. Love You!

Answer (score 1):

As @bayardcodeboy said

You just run flutter doctor -v
It will show a description of how to fix the problem.

For my problem, I run the command

```
flutter doctor -v

flutter config --android-studio-dir=F:\android_studio
```

Because I install it in drive F on my computer.
Hope this will help.